# How to listen to new forks in kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, fork, linux-device-driver

kernel: 3.4+

Does anyone know of any other way beside using kernel process events connector to "listen" to new forks.

I want to be simply notified in my module every time a new task (process) is created.

Comment: I don't understand why pnotify (http://lwn.net/Articles/153187/) never made it into the kernel, that would've been perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a [LSM hook](http://taiga.selinuxproject.org/~rhaines/NB4-diagrams/10-fork.png)
 to do this. The function you want to implement is security_task_create

Comment: that would entail creating a minimal LSM module, in effect replacing the default DAC or selinux LSM module. I do not want to replace the default LSM module just for the purpose of hooking...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the state of SystemTap but I think you can do a function boundary tracing like DTrace on Solaris using SystemTap. You'd need to know which linux kernel function to trace though, but that's the simpler part I presume.

Comment: "SystemTap provides free software (GPL) infrastructure to simplify the gathering of information about the running Linux system. This assists diagnosis of a performance or functional problem"

I am not looking at troubleshooting a problem but rather run-time information in my module so I can act upon it.

Comment: Wouldn't your requirement fall into the category of "gathering of information about the running Linux system"? I know for a fact that SystemTap lacks the intelligence/capacity to compel you to use this information to troubleshoot alone ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible hacks you could use to solve this.

You could hook the relevant syscall table entry, replace sys_fork with your code and call the original sys_fork.

Otherwise, you could hook sys_fork itself.